# How can I write a code which gives which one is better (comparing)

Tags: java, boolean, compare, operators

For a car are given the following characteristics:
- Age in years (age)
- Price in BGN (price)
A car is a high-end, if older than 5 years and cost over 20
thousand or 5 or fewer years and cost over 40 thousand
Write an expression that determines whether the vehicle is a given characteristic
high-end.
I tried with :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Vehicle {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Age: ");
    int age = input.nextInt();

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Price: ");
    int price = input1.nextInt();
       boolean isHightClass = age >= 5 && price > 20000 || age <= 5 && price > 4000;
    System.out.println(isHightClass);
```

Is it ok?

Comment: How can I use boolean to compare the age and the price if they are older than 5 years and cost over 20 thousand or 5 or fewer years and cost over 40 thousand?

Comment: You need some parentheses around the conditions that you want to AND. Otherwise you might not get it correctly.

Comment: @Arc676 No she doesn't.

Comment: @DavidWallace Why not? Or should I have said "it's recommended"?

Comment: It's simply not needed.  All the comparison operators are higher in the order of operations than `&&`, and `&&` is higher in the order of operations than `||`.  So Venetsia's code is correct as it stands - she doesn't need to add any parentheses.

Comment: Venetsia, the best way to tell whether your code is correct is to test it.  Think about how many different test cases you'd need, to make sure your logic is correct.  It's always more satisfying to see your code in action, than to take the word of other people about what it would do.

Comment: Thank you very much i don't know what i would do if you didn't help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to write in this way :

`boolean isHightClass = (age >= 5 && price > 20000) || (age <= 5 && price > 4000);`

Comment: It makes sense now :D thanks I didn't know if they were parentheses needed here

Comment: Yes. But it's a good practices to add parenthesis. Its separate the condition.

Comment: if i want them to make positive numbers how can i write the whole sentence ??

Comment: @VenetsiaKrusteva Not clear to me. Give some example.

Comment: For there to be a triangle with given lengths of the sides, these
countries should be positive integers and each country is less than the sum of the other 2 sides

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the price is greater than 4,000, not 40,000 as your question states.